# Searching for multiple strings using single database query with entity framework and LINQ

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-sql, entity-framework-6

Assuming I have a database table (aTable) with two columns

id : int

name: string

Requirements: 
I want to retrieve entries where aTable.name is like  a list of strings (stringsToSearchFor).

What I am doing: 
Currently I am using the following approach

```
var result=new List<aTable>; 
foreach (var aString in stringsToSearchFor)
    {
        var r = Context.Set<aTable>()
                .Any(s => s.name.Contains(searchString))
                .ToList();
        res.AddRange(r);
    }
return result.Distinct();
```

To optimize it I tried to change the code by eliminating the foreach, to be:

```
return Context.Set<aTable>()
                    .Any(s => stringsToSearchFor.Contains(s.name))
                    .Distinct()
                    .ToList();
```

However, this didn't provide the same results as the previous statement. I believe the first statement is correct.

My question: How can I search for multiple strings without creating N database queries (like the 2nd approach)?

Comment: I usually use Context.Set<aTable>().AsEnumerable().Select(x => x.Field<string>("name")).Distinct().ToList();.

Comment: This selects all entries in column name from the table. But I want to select entries that match (LIKE sql statement) a list of strings (not a single string)

Comment: Then use Context.Set<aTable>().AsEnumerable().Select(x => x.Field<string>("name")).Distinct().Where(x => stringsToSearchFor.Contains(x)).ToList();

Answer (score 2):

Alternative solution: use the EF 6.2 `Like`:

```
.Where(x => stringsToSearchFor.Any(s => DbFunctions.Like(x.name, "%" + s + "%")))
```

[Here's the documentation for `DbFunctions.Like`.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbfunctionsextensions.like?view=efcore-2.1)

Comment: Awesome solution! The only that I needed to change was $"%{s}%" to string concatenation because this translates to string. Format which EF can't understand. Thanks!

Comment: @ashilon Didn't think of that! I updated the answer to string concatenation to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
string[] stringsToSearchFor = new string[] { "text1", "text2" };

using (MyDbContext model = new MyDbContext())
{
    var result = model.aTable
        .Where(r => stringsToSearchFor.Any(s => r.name.Contains(s)))
        .ToList();
}
```